# End to end response time including rendering time performance test in jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

Is End to end response time is the combination of client side rendering time and server response time together.

I have executed load test in Jmeter and during steady state of test I have executed selenium test to get page rendering time

But my requirement is to get end to end response time. Do we need to add server response time and page rendering time to get end to end response time?

Answer (score 0):

> Is End to end response time is the combination of client side rendering time and server response time together.

No, It is only the server response time.

> I have executed load test in Jmeter and during steady state of test I have executed selenium test to get page rendering time

But the page rendering time also includes server response time. Hence you will end up adding server response time twice.

> But my requirement is to get end to end response time. Do we need to add server response time and page rendering time to get end to end response time?

By above arguments you should not add up server response time and page rendering time.

**Solution :-**

In my project we are using `Webdriver Sampler` plugin inside jmeter. It helps us to execute selenium scripts inside jmeter.

We have 2 Thread groups which runs parallel. First for Apis and second for running selenium scripts.

While the first Thread group generates load on server by hitting Apis. The second one navigates through Ui at the same time and captures load times.

With this approach you also get "near to realistic" data as this very much simulates production environment.

Hope this gives you some pointers in right direction.

Comment: I have a confusion, Do we have to execute Webdriver sampler only once or same as load test?

Comment: I think you can run it only once. But in parallel to load test.

Answer (score 0):

The time which Selenium gives you is end-to-end, you can get the breakdown of your page loading events by calling [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) via [WebDriver.executeScript()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) function

Just make sure that your JMeter test generates real-browser-like network pattern especially when it comes to [handling embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) and [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests